# no puede leer el id del xml

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo, wizard

esoty hacinedo un ,menu para que muestre las ventanas del pop up qu estoy diseñando pero a la hora de actualuizar esos cambios me mnada un error dice que no puede encontras un id estuve tratando de corregirlo pero me sigue mandando error

Adjunto codigo del menu:

````
```<odoo>
    <menuitem id="menu_3_mti_report_sale_terrestre"
              name="Informes(Terrestre)"
              parent="sale.sale_menu_root"
              sequence="1"/>

    <menuitem id="menu_mti_sale_report"
              parent="menu_3_mti_report_sale_terrestre"
              name="Numeros de referencia"
              action="mti_sale_report"
              sequence="2"
              />
   </odoo>```
````

asi es como estoy estructurando el menu en la carpeta views

archivo xml de la carpeta wizard

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <odoo>
<record id="mti_sale_report_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">referencias_sales_terrestre</field>
    <field name="model">mti_referencia</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group>
              <group>
                <field name="date_order"/>
              </group>
              <group>
                <field name="seller_id"/>
              </group>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="get_referencia_report" string="PDF Report" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="mti_sale_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
<field name="name">Informe de numeros de referencia</field>
<field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
<field name="res_model">mti_referencia</field>
<field name="view_mode">form</field>
<field name="target">new</field>
 </record>
       </odoo>```
````

y asi es como tengo el xml del wizard estuve haciendo cambios tratando de corregir el error pero nada me a funcionado que puedo hacer aqui para corregir el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desinstala el modulo y vuelve a instalar

Comment: no lo tengo instalado

Comment: pense que era eso pero el modulo no esta instalado

Comment: te muestro la estrcutura de las carpetas @Legna?

Comment: añadi la estructura @Legna

Comment: Y cual es el error que te da?

Comment: dice que no encuentra el id @Legna

Comment: y justo lo pone donde esta el menu dice que id que esta en el action no existe @Legna

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? No pegaste la traza del error. Es importante.

Comment: Revisaste que el wizard este registrado en el manifest?

Comment: si pude resolverlo pero ahora tengo otros errores no se si puedas ayudarme? @Legna